# db2,char for bit data,compare

Tags: db2, compare, hex

A field in java his type is GUID. In db2 his type is char for data type. I don't understand why (x'00345C9101600000018323B4F1311964BB' < x'00345C9101600000018323B4F1311964BB01') is false. is this not the comparation of Hexadecimal?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean 'varchar for bit data' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the SQL data type is character, string comparison rules apply, so the shorter string is padded with spaces on the right. The ASCII code for the space character is `x'20'`, which is greater than `x'01'`.

Comment: so cool,very very thank you,it has trouble me for a long time. like you,haha

Answer (score -1):

For the assigned hex value to be compared is too large to be calculated as the memory assigned for variable is limited, due to this it is throwing garbage value which is resulting to false result.

Comment: Thank you first. I do  this in db2,not in java. in db2 the field's value can be very long,so I don't understand why it will be limited.  I'm sorry not descrip my question clear before. I paste my sql :select * from "MD_DEPARTMENT" "MD_DEPARTMENT" where parents >= x'00345C9101600000018323B4F1311964BB' and parents <= x'00345C9101600000018323B4F1311964BB01'

Comment: It seemd so terrible to look. very sorry.  I think my sql can return some result, but it's empty result.